# Question about generalisation of the prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a polynomial with integer coefficients p(x).
Define $T(p)_n=T_n:= $ cardinality of$ \{x \leq n | p(x) $is prime$ \} $.
Is it known to what $T_n$ is asymptotic to depending on some choices of $p$? The prime number theorem corresponds to $p(x)=x$, where one obtains the famous asymptotic with x/ln(x). For which polynomials p does the limit $T_n/(n/ln(n))$ exist for n->$\infty$ and converge to something nonzero.

Comment: I think with our current state of knowledge this is tooooo difficult a question, although probabilistic number theory (of varying degrees of sophistication) can give very plausible heuristics for the true fact.

Comment: partial answers for specific choices of polynomials are fine too.

Comment: There is no polynomial in ***one variable,*** integer coefficients, for which it has been proved that it takes prime values infinitely many times. The one that is often mentioned is $x^2 + 1;$ no-one knows. Completely different as soon as we have two variables, such as $x^2 + y^2.$ see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture   "That $n^2 + 1$  should be prime infinitely often is a problem first raised by Euler, and it is also the fifth Hardy–Littlewood conjecture and the fourth of Landau's problems."